# Looking up older unitids

Tags: collegescorecard

We'd like to resolve older unitid -> opeid without referencing the crosswalk datafiles directly. However, lookups frequently fail.  The first unit id (and many others) present in the 1996-1997 crosswalk data serves as an example:

```
unitid,opeid,opeid6
100636,01230800,012308
```

Attempting to retrieve this from the API:

```
In [1]: rsp = requests.get('https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/school
     ...: s?api_key=8CoAdCZ2zCcLHf6ClaFCMPWwQMRWvVb4FVjKJHIY&fields=ope8_id%2Cid
     ...: &id=100636')

In [2]: rsp.json()
Out[2]: {'metadata': {'total': 0, 'page': 0, 'per_page': 20}, 'results': []}
```

Is there any way to look these up via the API and not have to access the CSV's?